# Calling Facebook PHP SDK 3 to pass user to AS3 Project

Tags: php, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-php-sdk, oauth-2.0

I'm having issues with loading the user's information into Flash from a PHP script.

**EDIT: index.php is called by Facebook to Authenticate. Flash then calls database.php to connect to the database and store/recall the players information and progress. Database.php then encodes the array and echos it out to Flash where it is parsed.**

This was working up until last weekend.

index.php

```
<?php
$app_id = "my_id";
$app_secret = "my_secret";
$my_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/my_app";

session_start();
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) 
{
$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
 $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state'];

 echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
 exit;
}

if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

 $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);

 $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
   . $params['access_token'];

 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 //echo("Hello " . $user->name);
 include_once 'game.php';
}
else 
{
    echo("The state does not match. Try opening the app from the homepage.");
    include_once 'game.php';
}
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => 'my_id',
 'secret' => 'my_secret',
));

// Get User ID
try 
    {
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) 
        {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            //$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
            //print_r($friends);
            mysql_connect("localhost", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS") or die("Could not connect");
        mysql_select_db("stus_zombies") or die("Could not select database");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook_id = " . $user_profile[id]);  
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        if(empty($result))
        { 
            $addInfo = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, facebook_id) 
            VALUES ('{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['id']}')");  
                $addInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());  

            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (facebook_id, coins, health, stamina, xp)
            VALUES ('{$user_profile['id']}','0','25','25','0')");
        }

        $checkProgress = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE facebook_id = " . $user_profile[id]);
        $playerCheck = mysql_fetch_array($checkProgress);

        $playerInfo = array(
        first_name => $user_profile[first_name],
            last_name => $user_profile[last_name],
            facebook_id => $user_profile[id], 
            //facebook_access_token => $_SESSION[fb_165114483572553_access_token],
            coins => $playerCheck[coins],
        health => $playerCheck[health],
        stamina => $playerCheck[stamina],
        xp => $playerCheck[xp],); 
        echo json_encode($playerInfo);
        } 

    else
    {
        echo ("No User");
    }
}

catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
{
    error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
?>
```

I changed to a different authentication method, and that worked for a couple hours before it stopped.

The second index.php I tried:

```
 <?php

 $app_id = "165114483572553";

 $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP";

 $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
 include_once 'game.php';
 } 
 ?>
```

AS3 Class database.as

```
package  
{
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import com.adobe.webapis.URLLoaderBase;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.*;
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
import org.flashdevelop.utils.FlashConnect;
import HUD.UI;

public class Database
{
    // Page Loader
    private static var loader:URLLoader;
    private static var dataloader:URLLoader;

    // User Info
    private static var playerData:Object;

    //TEST
    // Player Info
    private static var playerLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    private static var playerRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
    playerRequest.url = "http://MYURL/database.php";

    public function Database() 
    {

    }

    public function getPlayer():void
    {
        playerLoader.load(playerRequest);
        playerLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSONPlayer);
        playerLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    }
    // Decode JSON (Player Coins, ID, Stamina, Health, XP)
    private function decodeJSONPlayer(e:Event):void
    {
        playerLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        playerData = JSON.decode(playerLoader.data);
        loadPlayerInfo(playerData);
        // Display stats info
        UI.updateHealth();
        UI.updateMoney();
        UI.updateXP();
        UI.updateStamina();
    }

    // Load database info into player's data
    private function loadPlayerInfo(playerData:Object):void
    {
        Player.first_name = playerData.first_name;
        Player.last_name = playerData.last_name;
        Player.facebook_id = playerData.facebook_id;
        Player.facebook_access_token = playerData.facebook_access_token;
        Player.health = playerData.health;
        Player.stamina = playerData.stamina;
        Player.money = playerData.coins;
        Player.xp = playerData.xp;
        trace(playerData.first_name);
        // Display Facebook info
        UI.txtFacebookInfo.text = playerData.first_name +" " + playerData.last_name +" " + playerData.facebook_id;
    }

    // Save all Progress
    public static function setAll(_money:int, _health:int, _stamina:int, _xp:int):void
    {
        var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        vars.money = _money;
        vars.health = _health;
        vars.stamina = _stamina;
        vars.xp = _xp;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://MYURL/saveplayer.php");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = vars;

        if (loader != null)
        {
            loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, pageLoaded);
        }

        loader = new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        loader.load(request);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, pageLoaded);
    }

    private static function pageLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("PAGE LOADED\n============================");
        FlashConnect.trace(loader.data);
        trace("============================");
    }

    private static function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
        FlashConnect.trace(loader.data.dayNames);
    }

    // Server info not received
    private function onIOError(e:Event):void
    {
        trace ("Error loading URL");
    }
}

}
```

Changing it back to the original code worked till the next day before it stopped working.

I managed to get it working with a temporary fix by including the database script in with the index script and then calling it from Flash.

That just stopped working. Obviously this is driving me insane. Including database.php in index.php even now will <strike>trace</strike> echo out the JSON information correctly, but it isn't loaded into the game.

On the Flash side, I had it hooked up to a button so I could call it and see the return and it seemed to be working fine. I am never getting errors returned when it doesn't load the player's information which makes troubleshooting this trial and error and research.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent way too much of my time adapting scripts and researching at this point when there is someone out there that knows what is going on.

Comment: If you are getting your JSON data into the Database.as response then why would you think its a server side issue? You got the data where you need. You are probably not parsing it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, when I said trace out I meant it echo'd out in the browser. If I add dummy info to be encoded, it will update properly in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a domain issue with Facebook sometimes calling my domain with ssl which was different than the unsecured domain. Solved by forcing it and my app to call the secure domain.